# MonoTouch and unsafe floating point

Tags: xamarin.ios, arm, unmanaged, unsafe, memory-alignment

Can any one help me. I have this ‘unmanaged’ .NET code, which works on PC Platform and OSX with MonoTouch Device Simulator. But when I run the code on my iPad 2 device, it throws an exception. I have tried to make the code as simple to show the problem.

```
var buffer = new byte[ 8 ]; // Space for 2 float32.
float value = 123f;                                     

fixed (byte* ptr = &buffer[1])
{
    var fp = (float*)ptr;
    *fp = value;
}
```

On my device, it works when index in &buffer[] is 0, 4 - four bytes aligned as a float32, but fails on all other.

I’m interested to know, is it a bug in the MonoTouch unsafe implementation or is it me, that miss some information about .NET and unsafe code.

I have made a work-around, were I read/write in 4 byte buffer when handle floats, and then copies the data to the correct place in the array, but still it could be nice to know, if I miss understand something about .NET / iPad devices floating point handling or it is a bug. It is no problem with int64 types.

We are using unsafe array handling, because of tcp communication to PLC devices, were we uses arrays of uint8/uint16 and transfer blocks of data for gain higher throughput of data.

If anybody has time, here is a function for test, to try reproduce it:

```
BugTest(8); // Returns “S0,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,” On my pc and mac with iPad simulator.
BugTest(8); // Returns “S0,F1,F2,F3,S4,F5,F6,F7,” On my iPad device.


unsafe string BugTest(int numberOfIndexesTest)
{
    var testResult = new StringBuilder();
    var buffer = new byte[ numberOfIndexesTest + sizeof(float)];    
    float value = 123f;                                     

    for(var index=0; index<numberOfIndexesTest;index++)
    {
        try
        {
            fixed (byte* ptr = &buffer[index])
            {
                var fp = (float*)ptr;
                *fp = value;

                testResult.AppendLine(string.Format("S{0},", index));
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            testResult.AppendLine(string.Format("F{0},", index));
        }
    }

    return testResult.ToString ();
}
```

Thanks alot,

Best regards,
Casper Wollesen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a MonoTouch issue since you would have the same issue in C, C++, ObjectiveC...

The ARM processor, used in iOS devices, requires the `float` to be aligned on 4 bytes boundaries. The **x86** architecture does not have this requirement - which is why it works on the simulator, OSX, Windows...

**UPDATE:** [ARM structured alignment FAQ](http://www.aleph1.co.uk/chapter-10-arm-structured-alignment-faq)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nice to know what course the exception.

Comment: no problem. once solved you should mark the question as answered (green mark you can click) so anyone else searching stackoverflow can see there's an answer available. If you only liked the answer (but don't think it's complete) then you can just 'up vote' it (up arrow).  And of course you can do both (up vote and mark-as-answered). In doubt have a look at the FAQ - and welcome to stackoverflow.com